# how to mark two separate sets of duplicate values?

Tags: excel

Column A has employee name, column D has either a `Self` or `Manager` Assessment. The data exported weird, so I'm trying to find a way to quickly weed out what I'm looking to clean up.

If `A2 and A3` has the same employee name, I'd look to `D2 and D3` and make sure it has a manager assessment in A2 and a self assessment in A3. In this case, it's normal and I don't want mark it. When there is the same employee name in A2 & A3, and the same type of assessment (self) for both rows, I want to mark it so I can look at them.

What formula is there to identify one set of duplicates in one column and another in a separate column?

I was thinking of something like `=IF(A2=A1 & D2=D1,"Mark","")` or something like that, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax for that formula is:

```
=IF(AND(A2=A1,D2=D1),"Mark","")
```

Note that this will only find duplicates if they follow each other. i.e. if `A1/D1` and `A4/D4` match, the above formula won't find them as matching. For that you'll want to use:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,D$1:D1,D1)>1,"Mark","")
```

Which will mark all instances of a matching pair except the very first one.